# Can i use medium set mortar for cement board joints?

Tags: shower, tile

I'm installing large-format tile for a shower wall.  I've installed the cement backer board and I'm ready to tape/mortar the joints.  Everything I've read says to use thinset for this.  But I have a polymer-modified medium set, since that's what the large format tile requires.  Any reason I can't use this for the joints?  I don't want to buy a bag of thinset just for the scant amount the joints require.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine to use. Most any polymer modified medium set mortar is actually a thinset. It is just heavier bodied than "regular" thinset and used for greater support and stability on larger tiles.